# How many Distinct n variable boolean functions are there?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic

Since there are n variables wouldn't there be 2^n boolean functions?

Comment: Are you asking this *during* your exam?

Comment: no its an assignment question.

Answer (score 5):

For an n-ary boolean function, there are 2^n possible boolean inputs.  Each input can generate
either "true" or "false" as the output.  How many different ways can you arrange the 2^n true vs. false outputs?

Comment: I'd suggest writing out all the possibilities for n=1, n=2, and especially n=3, until the pattern becomes clear.  Don't want to say more than that, since it seems to be homework...

Comment: if n = 3 then there are 8 possible boolean inputs which is 2^3, and you can arrange the true or false 2 different ways for the output. so there are 2^(n+1) boolean functions

Comment: @Newf: For the 2^3 possible inputs, one function might give outputs [F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F].  Another function might give [F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T].  Yet another might give [F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F]. 2^(3+1) = 2^4 = 16 is too small to cover all the possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

If there are p possibilities for choice 1 and q possibilities for choice 2 then there are a total of p*q different ways of doing both.

It is trivial that this can be extended to n choices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

So, yeah, there would be 2^n boolean functions (as for each choice there are two alternatives).

Comment: I sure hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: You've calculated the number of possible inputs to a single n-ary boolean function, not the number of possible functions.

Comment: Well, then I didn't understand the question, how embarrassing.